# Unable to install the DreamHouse in salesforce

Tags: apex, dreamforce

I am new to the salesforce and trying to install the DreamHouse from the link : https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trails/force_com_dev_beginner/modules/platform_dev_basics/units/platform_dev_basics_intro.

When I tried to install that I am getting below. What could be the possible reason for failure ?

```
This app can't be installed.
There are problems that prevent this package from being installed.
(Command_Center) Validation Errors While Saving Record(s)   There were custom validation error(s) encountered while saving the affected record(s). The first validation error encountered was "You must have My Domain deployed to use component c:PropertyListDaysOnMarketChart.".
(Einstein_Vision) Validation Errors While Saving Record(s)  There were custom validation error(s) encountered while saving the affected record(s). The first validation error encountered was "You must have My Domain deployed to use component c:EinsteinVisionDashboard.".
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to install My Domain - a feature in Salesforce where you get a unique domain name.

For reference:

1. Find a domain name that’s available and sign up for it.
2. Customize the logo, background color, and right-frame content on your login page.
3. Add or change the identity providers available on your login page.
4. Test your domain name and deploy it to your entire org.
5. Set the login policy for users accessing your pages.

Please refer to [this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=domain_name_setup.htm&type=0) link for more information.